# stack_overflow in `list-based` quicksort in OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

Here is my implementation of `list-based` quicksort:

```
let partition pivot l = 
    let rec p left right = function
      | [] -> (left, right)
      | hd::tl ->
    let c = compare pivot hd
    in 
    if c > 0 then
      p (hd::left) right tl
    else 
      p left (hd::right) tl
    in
    p [] [] l;;

let quicksort l =
  let rec qs = function
    | [] -> []
    | pivot::tl ->
      let (left, right) = partition pivot tl
      in 
      (qs left) @ (pivot::(qs right))
  in 
  qs l;;
```

---

When I try it with a list of `100,000`, it is fine and has no problem.

However, if I try it with `1,000,000`, it gives error of `stack_overflow`.

---

I don't see why it gives `stack_overflow` as I think the stack size should be of like `log1000000 ~ 20`, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `@` operator is going to use a linear amount of stack, I would assume. (This is just one of the problems with doing quicksort on lists.)

Here is the definition of `@` from the Pervasives module:

```
let rec ( @ ) l1 l2 =
  match l1 with
    [] -> l2
  | hd :: tl -> hd :: (tl @ l2)
```

This is an exceptionally slow sort as it stands. If you really want this to work, you'll have to be a lot more clever. At the very least you'll need a tail recursive version of `@`.

Comment: Note that there is also `List.rev_append` which is tail recursive. Which means that you can: `let (@) l1 l2 = List.(rev_append (rev l1) l2)`

Comment: any other clever bit you can hint of to me?

Comment: I am also wondering why Pervasives implements @ like that. I assume list in ocaml is a linked list, right? why not just connect l1's last element with l2's first element?

Comment: ah, ok, it is like what I said above. It has to go through l1 first until it meets the last element of l1

Comment: Lists are immutable. So it creates a *copy* of `l1` whose last element "points to" `l2`. The old `l1` is not changed in the process.

Answer (score 1):

Quicksort is NOT to be used on linked lists. It doesn't work **well**. The correct sorting algorithm to use on lists is merge sort. 
Basically, as soon as you use list concatenation in your algorithm, you should realize that you're not doing it right, or that you should use an other data structure. Lists have many advantages, concatenation is NOT one of them.

Comment: well, I guess Quicksort does work on list, may not be as efficient as mergesort

Comment: well, I guess random sort also works on lists, may not be as efficient as mergesort. Of course every sort strategy works on everything, the reason we have different sorts, is because they are more efficient. If you are asked to write a sort for lists on a test or an interview, and you decide to implement quicksort, you won't have the points, or won't get hired.

Answer (score 0):

As already said, the problem is with @. This is not an unsolvable problem: you need to redefine the inner sorting function as a function that sort and concatenate.

```
 let partition pivot l = 
     let rec p left right = function
       | [] -> (left, right)
       | hd::tl ->
     let c = compare pivot hd
     in 
     if c > 0 then
       p (hd::left) right tl
     else 
       p left (hd::right) tl
     in
     p [] [] l;;

 let quicksort l =
   let rec qs l acc = 
   match l with
     | [] -> acc
     | pivot::tl ->
       let (left, right) = partition pivot tl
       in 
       qs left (pivot::(qs right acc)) 
   in 
   qs l [];;
```